# Issue with rails belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, belongs-to

Hey guys just trying to figure out why this does not work.
Basically this relationship does

```
belongs_to :product_category, :foreign_key => :category_id
```

And this one does not

```
belongs_to :category, :class_name => :product_category, :foreign_key => :category_id
```

The error message is "NameError: uninitialized constant product::product_category"

Why is that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter example does not work because there is no class called `product_category`. You are providing the wrong class name. Class names in Ruby should be written in CamelCase. When Rails looks for a `product_category` class it's not going to find it.

Your first example works because Rails infers the name of the class from the name of the relationship.

```
belongs_to :product_category, :foreign_key => :category_id
```

It converts `product_category` to `ProductCategory`. You can do the same thing yourself. Open up a terminal and type the following.

```
'product_category'.camelize.constantize
```

You should pass in a string instead:

```
belongs_to :category, :class_name => 'ProductCategory', :foreign_key => :category_id
```

But in this case it would be redundant since Rails can already infer the class name. The `class_name` argument should be used when the class name can not be inferred from the relationship name.